# SQL/Oracle 10g - Troubles with triggers/getting values from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm currently having an issue with a trigger I'm writing. I want to do a simple trigger in which after an update to table STATEMENT with the status field set to 'Sent', it would create a new row in the table NOTICE with fields such as id, date, user and the last field being a message which takes certain field values to create a "notice".

If it will help, my STATEMENT table contains the following fields:

- id
- List item
- Title
- Others not needed to know

So, with the last field of the NOTICE to be inserted, I want to create like a message, perhaps saying "The statement, (id) - (title), issued on (date) has been sent."

I currently have at the moment:

```
create trigger send_notice
    after update on STATEMENT
    for each row
    when (new.status = 'Sent')
begin
    insert into NOTICE values (notice_seq.nextval, SYSDATE, '10001', 'the notice 
    im having trouble constructing');
end send_notice;
```

I have tested this trigger in a database and everything seems to work fine. Another thing I was just wondering is if the formatting or if there is anything missing that might help with this trigger? And also, I would I go about creating that notice, which takes field values from STATEMENT?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to new STATEMENT column values in the trigger using :new., and concatenate them into your text:

```
create trigger send_notice
    after update on STATEMENT
    for each row
    when (new.status = 'Sent')
begin
    insert into NOTICE values (notice_seq.nextval, SYSDATE, '10001',
     'The statement, ' || :new.id || ' - ' || :new.title || ', issued on '
     || :new.issue_date || ' has been sent');
end send_notice;
```

Sometimes concatenating a lot of text and values can get confusing, and you may find it easier to use this "template" approach:

```
create trigger send_notice
    after update on STATEMENT
    for each row
    when (new.status = 'Sent')
declare
    l_text varchar2(500);
begin
    l_text := 'The statement, #ID# - #TITLE#, issued on #DATE# has been sent';
    l_text := replace (l_text, '#ID#', :new.id);
    l_text := replace (l_text, '#TITLE#', :new.title);
    l_text := replace (l_text, '#DATE#', :new.issue_date);
    insert into NOTICE values (notice_seq.nextval, SYSDATE, '10001', l_text);
end send_notice;
```

Comment: That works! thank you very much :) Also thank for the template approach. It is indeed less confusing.